# Replace ruby string with gsub with conditions for multiple strings

Tags: ruby

I have as string as "pas" and "with_pas". I want to replace it with blank string. Now I am doing as follows

```
string.gsub("pas","").gsub("with_pas","")
```

In some scenario i get the string as "pas" and in some other  with "with_pas".

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use your current approach, but will need to change the order, otherwise it won't work as expected:

```
string.gsub("with_pas","").gsub("pas","")
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using a regex?

```
string.gsub(/(with_)?pas/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.gsub(/pas|with_pas/, '').squeeze
```

This will remove the words and `squeeze` will remove the extra space that `gsub` added.